# How to customize annotations in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

Recently, I have been trying to add some text annotations to ggplot2 graphs using `annotate()` function. Here is a basic example;

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = "Some text")
```

The problem I am facing in using `annotate()` function is related to its customization. In other words, when I try to customize the text I want to add on the graph using basic CSS, `Some text`, such as changing the color and font size of `text` word, it does not allow me to do so. Therefore, I want to inquire how I can customize text annotations I want to put on the ggplot2 graphs? Thank you for your attention beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `?geom_text` you will see the aesthetics that can be applied to a text layer. The main ones are demonstrated below:

```r
p + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = "Some text",
             color    = "red",
             size     = 15, 
             family   = "serif", 
             fontface = "bold")
```

[image]

If you are desperate to use css instead of passing parameters to `annotate`, you could try loading the `ggtext` package and using `annotation` with `geom = "richtext"` instead of `geom = "text"`. It only covers a small subset of css (essentially just those properties shown above and one or two others)

```r
library(ggtext)

p + annotate(geom = 'richtext', x = 4, y = 25, color = NA, fill = NA,
             label='<span style="color:red; font-size:15mm; font-family:serif;">
                    <b>Some text</b></span>')
```

[image]

Comment: The latter option gives me a better level of customisation, which is exactly what I'm searching for. I appreciate you taking the time to write this response.